# Dropdown menu list folders

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, menu

I need to make a dropdown menu for a website i'm working on and in that dropdown i would like to list all files in a directory but due to my lack of web development knowledge i'm struggling a little to be able to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

```
<form>
<select name="menu">
<option value="http://www.msn.com/">MSN</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=this.form.menu.options[this.form.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</form>
```

That's about the extent to which i know how to make a dropdown menu

Comment: http://www.lateralcode.com/directory-trees-with-php-and-jquery/

Comment: Tell us what you have tried already and specifically what isn't working.

Comment: Do you have any relevant markup to post with your question? And what do you use to present the drop down? i.e., `jQuery`

Comment: I'm using html it's a very simple form for private use to allow my partner to submit to me ideas. I'm storing the data from each submittal in a directory so i'm basically just looking to list the different submittals in a dropdown which he could then select and then when he submits again the updated info would be written to that directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at PHP's [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function. Loop through the result and echo your HTML code, one `<option>` tag per loop iteration.

Something like this:

```
echo "<select name='files'>";
$files = array_map("htmlspecialchars", scandir("path/to/your/files"));
foreach ($files as $file)
    echo "<option value='$file'>$file</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Worked perfectly learned a lot off this as well didn't know i could just echo php into html like that (i'm very new to web development) thanks a ton though!

Comment: @user577732: Yeah, one thing to keep in mind is that PHP executes server-side. That means that PHP is completely done executing before your browser gets any text at all. HTML and Javascript are interpreted on the client-side. So you can use PHP to generate Javascript and HTML code. Once you grasp this concept, ideas of what you can and can't do will become much clearer to you.

Comment: yea i worked a lot with php today learned a lot, i come from java which i'm finding a lot of similarities between java and php so learning pretty quick

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<select>
<?php
  $source_dir = '/var/www/whatever';
  $dir_handle = opendir($source_dir);
  foreach (glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir_name) {
?>
  <option value="<?= htmlentities($dir_name) ?>">
    <?= htmlentities($dir_name) ?>
  </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

If you want to sort, filter, or whatever, just manipulate the array returned by [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) however you want.  Alternatively, you can use [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) calls followed by [`is_dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) calls.  There are a bunch of different ways to do it, it just boils down to your specific need.